# Problem with multiple calls in countdown timer in JS

Tags: javascript

i have an issue with my countdown timer function in JavaScript. My web page will be something like quiz game and i want to have 3 cases (for three sets of questions so i call the function 3 times). But when i am calling for first time function FireCountdown is going fine, but then if i call again the function(for the other 2 sets of questions) then my timer countdown is like "skiping" 2sec in every sec(9->7->5...) or like have 500ms and not 1000ms delay. Sorry but i am new in JS.

```
var timeLeft=10;
if(quiz1){
  document.getElementById("timer").className ="show";  
  FireCountdown();
}
else if(quiz2){
  document.getElementById("timer").className ="show";
  FireCountdown();  
}
else{
  document.getElementById("timer").className ="show";  
  FireCountdown();
}

function FireCountdown(){
 timeLeft=10;
  setInterval(function(){
    if(timeLeft <=0){
        clearInterval(timeLeft=0)
        document.getElementById("timer").className  ="hidden";      //disappear timer
        document.getElementById("question1").className  ="hidden";     //disappear question1
        document.getElementById("question2").className  ="hidden";     //disappear question2
        document.getElementById("question3").className  ="hidden";     //disappear question3
    }
    
    document.getElementById("countDownText").innerHTML=timeLeft;        //Timer print
    timeLeft -=1
  },1000)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must assign setInterval to a variable like:

```
window.timerInterval = setInterval(function(){};
```

and clear that before call setInterval again; like:

```
if(window.timerInterval) { clearInterval(window.timerInterval)};
```